# Make round corner TabLayout TabItem android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement the TabLayout like this:

[image: TabLayout like this]

Comment: Hello @AzimShaikh and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: How to Ask and Complete Examples

Comment: Take a look at the [Help].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make drawable `tab_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
   android:color="@android:color/transparent"></stroke>

<solid android:color="#23cf5a" />

</shape>
```

Tab Layout like as below

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Output

[image]

Comment: It's using TabLayout with TabItem @AzimShaikh 
, It might be help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `button` like this

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/cancelSOSButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
   android:text="GAMES"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:background="@drawable/round_corners_green"
   android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

Then create an **XML** file in `drawable` folder called **round_corners_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dip"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dip"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip"/>
</shape>
```

in colors.xml add this color

```
<color name="green">#3cb879</color>
```

Similarly, you can create buttons like this.

Result output

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create a xml(rounded_corner_button.xml) in drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/btn_green"/>
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/btn_green"
                android:width="2dp" />
            <corners
                android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then, call it in your button as background

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button"
```